npm выдает ошибку при попытке npm i, npm run dev, npm install @mui/x-data-grid
npm WARN While resolving: react-motion@0.5.2
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   18 more (@emotion/react, @emotion/styled, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^0.14.9  ^15.3.0  ^16.0.0" from react-motion@0.5.2
npm WARN node_modules/react-motion
npm WARN   react-motion@"^0.5.2" from react-vis@1.12.1
npm WARN   node_modules/react-vis
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^0.14.9  ^15.3.0  ^16.0.0" from react-motion@0.5.2
npm WARN   node_modules/react-motion
npm WARN     react-motion@"^0.5.2" from react-vis@1.12.1
npm WARN     node_modules/react-vis
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-vis@1.12.1
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.11.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     @emotion/react@"^11.11.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.11.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!       @emotion/styled@"^11.11.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       3 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system)
npm ERR!     3 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system)
npm ERR!   17 more (@emotion/styled, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.3" from react-vis@1.12.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-vis
npm ERR!   react-vis@"^1.12.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.3" from react-vis@1.12.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-vis
npm ERR!     react-vis@"^1.12.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-05-05T12_30_59_008Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-05-05T12_30_59_008Z-debug-0.log```

